# Powershell: Search in path, rename file and copy it

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build a script that can do the following
When I open the powershell script

1. it should ask me for a path where the files are located e.g.
   C:\SearchPath\DateOfToday
   Daily there will be a new folder e.g. 20221214.
   Maybe it is possible to specify the path and the script will get today's date by itself or maybe just opening a windows explorer so I can select the SourceFolder.
2. A file must be copied e.g. Test.xmr and then renamed to Test.$xmr
3. some more files should be collected like
   jpl, eml, html, pdf, cml, xmr, $xmr and xml
4. the collected files should be moved to the folder
   C:\AnotherFolder\

What I have so far is this

```
$SourceFolder = "\\Path1\Dateoftoday"
$DestFolder = '\\Path2' #Path to Destination Folder
[array]$FileList = gci -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -File -Filter "ABC.xmr"
[array]$FileList = gci -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -File -Filter "ABC.jpl"
[array]$FileList = gci -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -File -Filter "ABC.eml"
[array]$FileList = gci -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -File -Filter "ABC.html"
[array]$FileList = gci -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -File -Filter "ABC.pdf"
[array]$FileList = gci -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -File -Filter "ABC.cml"
[array]$FileList = gci -Path $SourceFolder -Recurse -File -Filter "ABC.xml"
ForEach ($F in $FileList) {
    Copy-Item $F.FullName (Join-Path $DestFolder ($F.Name))
}
```

I can specify the path and the filenames and then run it.
Sorry if it's basic, but I'm new at powershell.

Comment: Do you want to **copy** (as in title) or **move** (as in question) the files? Have you thought of naming collisions when files from today have the same name and extension as the day before?

Comment: you're right. I want to copy them. 
There should be no naming collision because each file has a different extension.

Comment: I wouldn't be to sure about that, since you added switch `-Recurse`, where files with the same name can occur in different subfolders. Plus.. Do you also have a new destination folder each day?

Comment: My DestionationFolder is always the same. It's a folder where another app grabs that copied files and processes them. 

I have a new SourceFolder every day. Another app is moving files into that folder when something is wrong with the Job.

Sometimes it happens that files are missing so I'm right now copying them manually. I want to automate that a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need this:

```
$today        = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date)
$SourceFolder = "\\Path1\$today"
$DestFolder   = '\\Path2' #Path to Destination Folder
$filePattern  = '*.xmr', '*.jpl', '*.eml', '*.html', '*.pdf', '*.cml', '*.xml', '*.$xmr'

# unclear about your question 2)..
# do we need to copy a file to the $SourceFolder first ??
# Copy-Item -Path 'X:\Somewhere\Test.xmr' -Destination (Join-Path -Path $SourceFolder -ChildPath 'Test.$xmr')

# copy all chosen files to the destination folder
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceFolder -Recurse -File -Include $filePattern | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $DestFolder
}
```

---

As per your comment, hopefully this is what you need:

```
$today        = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date)
$SourceFolder = "\\Path1\$today"
$DestFolder   = '\\Path2'          #Path to Destination Folder
$extensions   = 'xmr', 'jpl', 'eml', 'html', 'pdf', 'cml', 'xml'

# ask for the filename
$baseName = Read-Host 'Please enter the file name without extension'
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($baseName)) {
    # construct the filenames to copy
    $pattern = $extensions | ForEach-Object { '{0}.{1}' -f $baseName.Trim(), $_ }
    # copy all chosen files to the destination folder
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceFolder -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object { $pattern -contains $_.Name } | ForEach-Object {
        # rename the extensions by prefixing it with a dollar sign ($)
        $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $DestFolder -ChildPath ('{0}.${1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension.TrimStart("."))
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetFile

        # if you want ONLY the .xmr file to be renamed with as .$xmr use this instead:
        # if ($_.Extension -eq '.xmr') {
        #     $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $DestFolder -ChildPath ('{0}.${1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension.TrimStart("."))
        #     $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetFile
        # }
        # else {
        #     $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $DestFolder
        # }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

As you commentd you want to remove the leftover .xmr and .att files after copying, here the code that does that too

```
$today        = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date)
$SourceFolder = "\\Path1\$today"
$DestFolder   = '\\Path2'          #Path to Destination Folder
$extensions   = 'xmr', 'jpl', 'eml', 'html', 'pdf', 'cml', 'xml', 'att'

# ask for the filename
$baseName = Read-Host 'Please enter the file name without extension'
if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($baseName)) {
    # construct the filenames to copy
    $pattern = $extensions | ForEach-Object { '{0}.{1}' -f $baseName.Trim(), $_ }
    # copy all chosen files to the destination folder
    (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceFolder -Recurse -File) | 
    Where-Object { $pattern -contains $_.Name } | ForEach-Object {
        # rename the extensions by prefixing it with a dollar sign ($)
        $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $DestFolder -ChildPath ('{0}.${1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension.TrimStart("."))
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetFile

        # if you want ONLY the .xmr file to be renamed with as .$xmr use this instead:
        # if ($_.Extension -eq '.xmr') {
        #     $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $DestFolder -ChildPath ('{0}.${1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension.TrimStart("."))
        #     $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetFile
        # }
        # else {
        #     $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $DestFolder
        # }

        # remove leftover .XMR and .ATT files
        if ($_.Extension -match '\.(xmr|att)$') { $_ | Remove-Item -Force }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's missing is 
1. ask for a file name and then copy this files with the file pattern to destination folder
2. rename the copied files to e.g. XRM to $XMR

Comment: @BehindYou Do you mean **al*l copies must be renamed so that each extension is prefixd wih `$`, or just the `.XMR` file?

Comment: it's just one file for now. I can add them later if I need to rename more. 

It's more important that it takes only the file with the given name because in that folder are more files. I don't want to copy them all to my destination folder.

Comment: it's not working. It asks me for a filename. I copy at inside the running powershell and it still copies all files from sourcefolder to destinationfolder.

Optional:
Can you seperatly tell me what I need to change when I want to rename from $XMR -> XMR. For me this looks so complicated and cryptic :-D

Comment: e.g. the filename is "20221214230708544_96629334" and I've a 9 filetypes of this file all with the different extension. In that same folder are 200 other files but they have different names. I just want to copy "20221214230708544_96629334" this file with 9 filetypes. 

20221214230708544_96629334.$xmr
20221214230708544_96629334.xmr
20221214230708544_96629334.att0
20221214230708544_96629334.cml
20221214230708544_96629334.eml
20221214230708544_96629334.html
20221214230708544_96629334.jpl
20221214230708544_96629334.pdf
20221214230708544_96629334.xml

Comment: @BehindYou ...But... you **want** it to copy the all files with the given name and any of the given extensions don't you? In my new code you can see how a new filename is created by joining the destination path with the filename where this: `'{0}.${1}' -f $_.BaseName, $_.Extension.TrimStart(".")` inserts the dollar sign to the extension. Have a look at the [-f Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f) to see how that works (really simple)

Comment: @BehindYou Ah, tested and the problem is with the `-Include` part. I have now replaced that with a Where-Object clause.

Comment: I tested the script today. 

How can I delete original copied xmr and att files? They are leftovers and don't need to be in the destionation folder after processing is done. I played with Remove-Item a little bit but I don't get it how to give him the command to only delete $baseName with XMR and ATT extension.

Regarding your link to learn the -f format operator. I don't understand why they use {1,-10} -> for what is the -10? Output is "hello" but why -10? I first thought 10 characters but when I type in something with 11 characters it displays this as well.

Comment: @BehindYou Please see my edit to remove leftover .xmr and .att files. As for the `"{0} {1,-10} {2:N}" -f 1,"hello",[math]::pi` syntax shown as example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f): the ,-10 is to prefix (or postfix) a value with 10 spaces in order to align output. The example add 10 spaces after the second value `"hello"` to separate it from the next value which is `math]::pi`

Comment: @BehindYou Also, being new to the platform, may I ask you to read the [tour] where you can see how to mark a question 'done' if an answer solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Good day!!

Maybe we can help you with this:
First of all you need to ask for the path and we have two ways to do this (maybe more) but those are the ways I know

The first option is the simple, using the Read-Host Cmdlet:

```
$path = Read-Host "Please type the path of the folder"
```

The second option is more complicated and use dotnet framework: (to ask for the destination just change the last two variables with destination instead of sourcePath)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$box = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$box.Text = 'Script Execution'
$box.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$box.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,120)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$okButton.Text = 'OK'
$okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$box.AcceptButton = $okButton
$box.Controls.Add($okButton)

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,120)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$cancelButton.Text = 'Cancel'
$cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$box.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$box.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.Text = 'Please type the path of the files:'
$box.Controls.Add($label)

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$box.Controls.Add($textBox)

$box.Topmost = $true

$box.Add_Shown({$textBox.Select()})
$result = $box.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $sourcePath = $textBox.Text
    $sourcePath
}
```

Once we have the path we can copy the files to do it we can use Copy-item
(I'm not sure if you want to rename the original files or the final files, anyway if you want to rename the last files just use rename-item cmdlet)

```
$fileList = @(
    Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse -include "*.jpl", "*.eml", "*.html", "*.pdf", "*.cml", "*.xml"
)

foreach ($f in $fileList){
   Copy-Item -Path $f.fullname -Destination "$destPath\$f.name"
}
```

And this should be enough, i'm not really sure about the $fileList part maybe I made some typo, sorry in this case.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank you for the script that looks very promising. 

Two questions:
a) is there a possibility to ask for the filename after the path and search the files accordingly? Because the filenames change.

b) I want to rename only final files (XML and XMR) to $XML and $XMR.

c) When I start the script from the desktop with a double click, Powershell opens and closes again immediately. Is it possible to add a pause at the end here or an output with "processing done"?

Comment: Sure, to ask for the FileName you just need to make a new box changing the variables and adding the last variables to the search.
And to rename the files ending with these extensions just use *.XML or *.XMR in the parameters

About the opening and close, maybe some line is wrong, open a Powershell then execute the script, it should give you the errors

Comment: I rightclick the ps1 file copy and paste the example path in and I get this error message. I think it has something to do with "$destPath\$f.name".


Copy-Item : Das Laufwerk wurde nicht gefunden. Ein Laufwerk mit dem Namen "\C" ist nicht vorhanden.
In C:\Users\Username\xyz\Desktop\Rename_Copy_Move.ps1:52 Zeichen:4
+    Copy-Item -Path $f.fullname -Destination "$destPath\$f.name"
+    ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\C:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand